# jQuery object data structure

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a mini jQuery clone that can support method chaining. So far I've came up with this piece of code:

```
var $ = (function () {

  var elements = [];

  function methodOne() {
    console.log('Method 1');
    return this;
  }

  function methodTwo() {
    console.log('Method 2');
    return this;
  }

  return {
    methodOne: methodOne,
    methodTwo: methodTwo
  };
}());
```

At page load, the `$` variable gets populated with the jQuery clone object returned by the IIFE.

My question is, how can I make the `$` object to be called directly as a function while still maintaining the method chaining functionality?

Right now, I can use `$.methodOne().methodTwo()` but I cant use `$('some parameter').methodOne().methodTwo()` just like jQuery does.

Comment: I haven't tried but I think you could use the `class` javascript and `extends` Jquery! I think that will do it. You know, I'm curious and I will try too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var $ = function (param) {

  var elements = [];
  console.log(param);

  function methodOne() {
    console.log('Method 1');
    return this;
  }

  function methodTwo() {
    console.log('Method 2');
    return this;
  }

  return {
    methodOne: methodOne,
    methodTwo: methodTwo
  };
};

$('This is a param').methodOne().methodTwo();
```

Answer (score 1):

[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p6fx5hL0/1/). The comments should be more or less self explanatory.

It might look a bit long, but it will let you create new mini jQuery object every time you call it.

```
var _ = (function () {

    var Magic = function(query){
        if(window === this)
            return new Magic(query);

        // reference to itself
        var that = this;

        //assign pseudo public methods and variables
        that.elements = [];
        that.methodTwo = methodTwo;
        that.methodOne = methodOne;

        //fills inner element array with DOM element 
        _get(query);

        function _get(query){
            var elem = document.getElementById(query);
            that.elements.push(elem);
        }

        function methodOne() {
            console.log('Method 1');
            return that;
        }

        function methodTwo() {
            console.log('Method 2', that.elements);
            return that;
        }

        return this;
    } 

    //returns function, which is assigned to a "_" variable
    return function(query){
        //everytime "_" is called, it will return new instance for object Magic which makes all the work
        return new Magic(query);
    } 

}());
```